# Parsing text to array in PHP or jQuery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, parsing

```
<?php 

$list = "<tr>
          <td>1.</td>
          <td>aaa</td>
          <td>234234</td>

          <td>1.</td>
          <td>bbb</td>
          <td>23423423</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2.</td>
          <td>ccc</td>

          <td>5644</td>
          <td>2.</td>
          <td>ddd</td>
          <td>4566456</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>3.</td>

          <td>eee</td>
          <td>456456</td>
          <td>3.</td>
          <td>fff</td>
          <td>456456456</td>
        </tr>
"; ?>
```

CODEPAD: http://codepad.org/JaxTfBF6

How can i get all values from second and the fifth TD in each TR from variable $list?
i would like receive array. I can use PHP or jQuery.

```
$all = array('aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd', 'eee', 'fff');
```

Comment: If you already have the data server-side, why would you want to send it to client-side ,parse it with jQuery, and then back to server-side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var text = "<tr><td>1.</td><td>aaa</td><td>234234</td><td>1.</td><td>bbb</td><td>23423423</td></tr><tr><td>2.</td><td>ccc</td><td>5644</td><td>2.</td><td>ddd</td><td>4566456</td></tr><tr><td>3.</td><td>eee</td><td>456456</td><td>3.</td><td>fff</td><td>456456456</td></tr>";

var output = $(text).find("td:nth-child(2), td:nth-child(5)").map(function() {
    return $(this).text();
});

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

This would be pretty easy with jQuery.

You could load DOM objects from the string:

```
var values = [];
var domObj = $( input_string );

$( 'tr:nth-child(5)', domObj ).each( function() {

   values.push( this.val() );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use jQuery:

```
var list = $('td:nth-child(2), td:nth-child(5)').map(function(){
   return $(this).text();
}).get()
```

It basically retrieves the fifth element of every `td` and then applied a function to each element, which replace the element itself with its text content.

Answer (score 1):

With PHP you can use [DOM or simpleXML](http://no.php.net/manual/en/refs.xml.php) libraries to parse HTML or regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

It seems as if you already have the data on your server, so there is no reason to send it to the client, use jQuery to parse it, and then send it back to PHP.

Given your input array `$list` in PHP, you can do the following.

First match all `<td>` elements

```
if (preg_match_all('/<td>(.*)<\/td>/U', $list, $res))
    $res = end($res);
```

Then filter out all the wrong rows.

```
$count = 0;
$res = array_filter($res, function($item) use (&$count) {
    return (++$count%3==2);
});
```

Finally remove the old keys in the array and return it.

```
$res = array_values($res);
print_r($res);
```

The above should return

```
Array (
    [0] => aaa       [1] => bbb       [2] => ccc
    [3] => ddd       [4] => eee       [5] => fff
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the other answers, but complete working code...

```
var all = [];

$("tr").each(function() {
    $(this).find("td:nth-child(2)").each(function() {
        all.push($(this).val());
    });
    $(this).find("td:nth-child(5)").each(function() {
        all.push($(this).val());
    });
})
```

Comment: No reason for downvotes? I'd like an explanation so I know what's wrong with the code.

Comment: @PaulAttuck Thanks Paul, but I just wanted to know what people _though_ was wrong with it.  I tested it and it works so if it's bad code then I'd rather know why so I can learn from it.